# Skip analyzing of internal types in FxCop

Tags: c#, fxcop

Is it possible to have FxCop ignore/skip analyzing of internal interfaces and classes in a given assembly?

I'm not interested in specifying all public interfaces and classes to FxCop (as analyze only these). This would mean that every time a new public type is added I have to go to FxCop's configuration and add this new type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some rules ignore non-public types by default.  However, there is no global setting for preventing those that do not from executing against non-public types, so you're pretty much stuck with your manual type selections.

That said, I would strongly recommend that you reverse your approach and include all types by default, manually excluding those types that you wish to ignore.  This will prevent you from missing problems in a public type simply because you forgot to include it in analysis.